# While implementing an interface in an enum, why eclipse automatically puts a semicolon before the interface method being overridden?

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, interface, syntax-error

I have an `interface` and an `enum`

I am implementing the `interface` in the `enum`

I am using `eclipse` as my IDE

Following is my `interface` file -

`ITrafficSignal.java` -->

```
public interface ITrafficSignal {
    public void showAction();
}
```

Following is my `enum` file -

`ETrafficSignal.java` -->

```
public enum ETrafficSignal implements ITrafficSignal {
    ;

    @Override
    public void showAction() {

    }
}
```

here the `;` in line 2 is being automatically being put by `eclipse`

If I remove `;`, then in the `method` being `implemented` -

`public void showAction()`

is having a red line below the `keyword` `void` and the error says -

```
Multiple markers at this line 
- implements ITrafficSignal.showAction
- Syntax error on token "void", volatile expected
```

I am unable to understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simply the syntax of enum types. From [§8.9 Enum Types of the *Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> ```
> EnumDeclaration:
>   {ClassModifier} enum TypeIdentifier [Superinterfaces] EnumBody
> ```

And the syntax of `EnumBody` is:

> ```
> EnumBody:
>   { [EnumConstantList] [,] [EnumBodyDeclarations] }
>
> EnumConstantList:
>   EnumConstant {, EnumConstant}
>
> EnumConstant:
>   {EnumConstantModifier} Identifier [( [ArgumentList] )] [ClassBody]
>
> EnumConstantModifier:
>   Annotation
> ```

And finally the syntax of `EnumBodyDeclarations` is:

> ```
> EnumBodyDeclarations:
>   ; {ClassBodyDeclaration}
> ```

As you can see, the above shows that the enum body declarations must be preceded by a semicolon (`;`) separating it from the enum constants. Unlike the `EnumConstantList` the semicolon is not optional<sup>1</sup>. This means the semicolon must be present if there's enum body declarations regardless of there being any enum constants declared, though I personally don't see the point in having an enum type without constants.

---

<sup>1. The entire `EnumBodyDeclarations` is optional, however, meaning if there's no body declarations then the semicolon can be omitted.</sup>

Comment: Good answer, somehow I knew that it was needed, but never cared to look at the spec. Also to the statement: *though I personally don't see the point in having an enum type without constants.*, [`enum`s can (sadly) be used like static classes for holding utility methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992893/using-enums-to-implement-utility-classes-and-singletons)